# Keeping view's hidden status when exporting MS CRM 2011 solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have faced with strange flaw of MS CRM 2011 deployment process.

Developer is able to deactivate views on development system, however it's impossible to transfer this customization to the target system via solution. Here is [relevant blog post about this issue](http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2011/09/some-assembly-required-unmanaged-solution-gotchas.html), "View Status" topic.

But maybe this operation is possible to perform via direct XML editing?

Otherwise if solution is managed, it's impossible to modify view's status on target system... Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem when moving our Testing environment to Staging.

If you are referring to moving the custom views (i.e. user created dashboards) you are correct there is no way to include this with the solution. This is a known “Feature” of CRM 2011.

However, it is possible to create a [Scribe](http://www.scribesoft.com/Insight) job that enables you to transfer the views over to the new solution/environment once you have it set up.